# Is there a way to add an OR condition in a routing file in Angular 14

Tags: angular

I've 3 paths and all those paths should redirect to the same component only. Currently my routing file is this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'ict/car-details', component: CarDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'ict/parts', component: PartsComponent },
  { path: 'ict/bike-details', component: BikeDetailsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'ict/car-details/upload-documents',
    component: DocUploadComponent,            
  },
  {
    path: 'ict/parts/upload-documents',
    component: DocUploadComponent,             
  },
  {
    path: 'ict/bike-details/upload-documents',
    component: DocUploadComponent,          
  },
];
```

Notice the last three routes. `DocUploadComponent` is common for all three components i.e. CarDetails, Part and BikeDetails. Is there a way to club them together. Is there any OR condition or something. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameterlized routes

Ex:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'ict/car-details', component: CarDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'ict/parts', component: PartsComponent },
  { path: 'ict/bike-details', component: BikeDetailsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'ict/:type/upload-documents',
    component: DocUploadComponent,            
  },
];
```

then read it as follows

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.type = params['type']; 
    });

    // or
    // this.type = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('type');

  }
```

Comment: this would work but i would probably add canActivate gaurd on it, or if you using latest angular use canMatch with this.